# Django form.cleaned_data is None

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

This is my form:

```python
class EventForm(forms.Form):
    start_date       = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span6 as-date'}))
    end_date         = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'span6 as-date'}))
    title            = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span8'}))
    description      = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'class': 'span8'}))
    total_seats      = forms.IntegerField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span6'}))
    buffer_seats     = forms.IntegerField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span6'}))
    seat_cost        = forms.IntegerField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span8'}))
    published        = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'span6'}))
    verified_booking = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'span6'}))

def clean(self):
    try:
        self.cleaned_data['start_date'] = datetime.strptime(self.cleaned_data['start_date'], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
    except ValueError:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Improper start date')
    try:
        self.cleaned_data['end_date'] = datetime.strptime(self.cleaned_data['end_date'], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
    except ValueError:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Improper end date')
    if self.cleaned_data['buffer_seats'] >= self.cleaned_data['total_seats']:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Seats buffered can not be same or greater than total seats')
    if self.cleaned_data['start_date'] >= self.cleaned_data['end_date']:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Event start date can not be greater than end date')
    if self.cleaned_data['published'] == 'on':
        self.cleaned_data['published'] = True
    else:
        self.cleaned_data['published'] = False
    if self.cleaned_data['verified_booking'] == 'on':
        self.cleaned_data['verified_booking'] = True
    else:
        self.cleaned_data['verified_booking'] = False
```

Here's the view:

```python
event_form = EventForm(request.POST)
if event_form.is_valid():
   event = events_api.save_event_from_form(request.user, address, event_form.cleaned_data)
```

But I'm getting `event_form.cleaned_data` as `None`. What am I missing?

Comment: you forgot the `return` in your clean() method

Comment: No incorrect, `return` is not necessary. See comment bellow accepted answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`form.clean()` **must** return `cleaned_data`. The canonical implementation is:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # ...
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        # do your custom validations / transformations here
        # and some more
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: That is actually incorrect. It **must not** return `cleaned_data`. The reason why this solution worked was because of `cleaned_data = super().clean()` which was the missing part. Interesting that nobody pointed that out until today. Returning `cleaned_data` is not necessary. It is tho, when you clean a specific field with `clean_fieldname`.

Comment: @lapin: you seem to be actually right about returning `cleaned_data` not being strictly required - looking at `Form._clean_form()`, it only rebinds `self.cleaned_data` if it's not `None` so the OP's implementation should have worked indeed. This being said,  since the default `Form.clean()` implementation just returns `self.cleaned_data`, you're also wrong about the `super().clean()` call being responsible for solving the issue - unless the OP's code snippet is inexact or incomplete that is.